# Looping Pages in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My facing issue is how to create looping such explanation below……?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9-9eJW3sN3tS0hnMU9pd29SX2s/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is not the best solution but as a workaround you can store all the locators for radio button in an external file such as property or excel with their corresponding price which you want to verify.

You can iterate a loop till the count of radio button to perform same action.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class StackOverFlow {

    @Test
    public static void keepClicking(){

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm");

        List<WebElement> radios = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentbar']/div/table[1]//input[@type='radio']"));

        for (int i = 0; i < radios.size(); i++) {

            // if you are getting stale element exception because of the page reload
            radios = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentbar']/div/table[1]//input[@type='radio']"));

            System.out.println(radios.get(i).getAttribute("value"));

            // select your radio and click to go to next page
            radios.get(i).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentbar']/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/input[4]")).click();

            // come back to your main page
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='contentbar']/div/p[2]/a")).click();
        }
    }

}
```

---

Run the above code to check - you have multiple radio button, going to the next page, coming back to the main page and clicking on the next radio - in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.navigate()
            .to("https://www.garuda-indonesia.com/other-countries/en/index.page");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-4")).click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                    .id("originairportcode"))).sendKeys("j");
    wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                    .cssSelector("div#autocomplete-originairportcode ul#ui-id-9  li#CGK a")))
            .click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("destairportcode")).sendKeys("bali");
    ;
    wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By
                    .cssSelector("div#autocomplete-destairportcode ul#ui-id-16 li#DPS a")))
            .click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("departuredate")).click();
    List<WebElement> ddate = driver.findElements(By
            .cssSelector("a.ui-state-default"));
    for (WebElement dd : ddate) {
        if (dd.getText().equals("30")) {
            dd.click();
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("arrivaldate")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all"))
            .click();
    List<WebElement> rdate = driver.findElements(By
            .cssSelector("a.ui-state-default"));
    for (WebElement dd : rdate) {
        if (dd.getText().equals("31")) {
            dd.click();
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("inputFormBookFlight")).submit();
    List<WebElement> allRadios = wait
            .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                    .xpath("//div[@class='divtableResultsSD']/table/tbody/tr/td/table[@id='left']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input")));
    driver.findElement(By.id("btnCheckPriceSdai")).click();
    driver.navigate().back();
    //first radio button is already selected,start index with 1
    for (int i = 1; i < allRadios.size(); i++) {
        allRadios = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By
                        .xpath("//div[@class='divtableResultsSD']/table/tbody/tr/td/table[@id='left']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/input")));
        allRadios.get(i).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnCheckPriceSdai")).click();
        driver.navigate().back();
    }
    driver.close();

}
```